# Akita persistState with capacitor Storage

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, akita

Is it possible to combine akita persistState function with the capacitor Storage plugin like this?

```
persistState({ storage: Storage});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If its posible ... I forgot question Mark

Comment: Yah, I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

No. `storage` object in akita `persistState` method is of type `PersistStateStorage`, that is

```
export interface PersistStateStorage {
    getItem(key: string): MaybeAsync;
    setItem(key: string, value: any): MaybeAsync;
    clear(): void;
}
```

Capacitor Storage has is of Type `StoragePlugin` which has get(), set() methods on it.

Comment: My solution is was to create a Storage Service which uses Capacitor Storage and implements the PersistStorage interface.

Comment: Hi @cedricblaser01 could you share your service code? I'm having the same issue atm. Thanks!!!